# calculating one side of a triangle knowing 2 sides and an angle (trigonometry)

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

There are two farms, $A$ and $B$ and there are two roads from each one. The roads intersect at a 68° angle, in $C$. The $A$ Farm is at $230 m$. of $C$ and the $B$ farm at $435m$. what's the lenght of $AB$?

So i made the triangle and i drew the height $CH$ from $C$,. So, let $\alpha$ be the angle $BCH$, so the angle $AHC$ will be $68-\alpha$[image]
So;$$\cos(\alpha)=\frac{CH}{AC}=\frac{CH}{435}$$ and $$\cos(68-\alpha) = \frac{CH}{230}$$
now
$$435\cos(\alpha)=230\cos(68-\alpha)$$
But i'm still lost. Am i missing some properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Law of Cosines: For $\triangle ABC$, we have $$\cos C = \frac{AC^2+BC^2-AB^2}{2\cdot AC\cdot BC}$$
which you can use to solve $AB$ directly: $$AB = \sqrt{AC^2+BC^2-2\cdot AC\cdot BC \cdot \cos C}$$

Comment: I can't believe i forgot the law of cosines lol thanks